# Using redirection within the script produces a unicode output. How to emit single-byte ASCII text?

Tags: unicode, powershell

I am using [Sandcastle Helpfile Builder](http://www.codeplex.com/SHFB) to produce a helpfile (.chm).  The project is a .shfbproj file, which is XML format, works with msbuild.

I want to automatically update the Footer text that appears in the generated  .chm file. I use this snippet:

```
$newFooter = "<FooterText>MyProduct v1.2.3.4</FooterText>";

get-content  -Encoding ASCII $projFile.FullName | 
    %{$_ -replace '<FooterText>(.+)</FooterText>', $newFooter } > $TmpFile

move-item $TmpFile $projFile.FullName -force
```

The output directed to the $TmpFile is always a multi-byte string. But I don't want that. How do I set the encoding of the output to ASCII?

Comment: Thanks Powershell for defaulting to an obscure output format (UCS-2 which was replaced in 1996!!??). utf8 would have been fine ;)

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40098771/changing-powershells-default-output-encoding-to-utf-8

Comment: It's possible to mix encodings with ">>" too.  I would stick with set-content and add-content.

Comment: @LimitedAtonement: Yes, that decision was unfortunate, but fortunately the problem was rectified in PowerShell _Core_ (v6+), where BOM-less UTF-8 is now the default. As an aside: what Windows PowerShell by default uses with `>` / `Out-File` (but not with `Set-Content`) is _UTF-16LE_ (which is part of the Unicode standard and won't go away), _not_  UCS-2 (which is indeed obsolete, because it couldn't represent _all_ Unicode characters).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could change the [$OutputEncoding](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/outputencoding-to-the-rescue/) variable before writing to the file. The other option is not to use the `>` operator, but instead pipe directly to `Out-File` and use the `-Encoding` parameter.

Comment: the > operator is actually an alias to out-file, which defaults to utf. tomasr is correct that you should use out-file specifically to set the encoding.

Comment: @JamesPogran What about `2>` ? I'm not sure how, in PowerShell to run a command like `cmd > out 2> err` through the pipes to out-file (explicitly specifying an encoding).  Also, "which defaults to utf"; what do you mean by utf? utf8? utf16? utf32? I thought the default is UCS-2 anyway, not UTF (UCS Transfer Format); did you see it documented otherwise somewhere?

Comment: The `Out-File -Encoding` recommendation is helpful, but `$OutputEncoding` does _not_ apply here, because it is unrelated to `>` / `>>`. Its sole purpose is to define the encoding to use when sending data from PowerShell _to an external program_.

Comment: e.g.  `git diff HEAD~1 HEAD | Out-File -Encoding ascii patch.txt`

Comment: Your link is dead

Answer (score 13):

The `>` redirection operator is a "shortcut" to `Out-File`. `Out-File`'s default encoding is Unicode but you can change it to ASCII, so pipe to `Out-File` instead:

```
Get-Content -Encoding ASCII $projFile.FullName |
    % { $_ -replace '<FooterText>(.+)</FooterText>', $newFooter } |
    Out-File $tmpfile -Encoding ASCII
```

Comment: Zomfg what a pain in the ass, http://stackoverflow.com/q/8216027/124486 So, essentially `generate_bat_file.pl > run_all.bat` is totally useless because executing a bat file -- even in PowerShell -- will result in an error if that `.bat` file is encoded in UTF16.

Answer (score 7):

`| sc filename` does the trick (sc being an alias for Set-Content)

for `>> filename` use `| ac filename` does the trick (ac being an alias for Add-Content)

Comment: `>>` can mix encodings in the same file too.

Answer (score 4):

I found I had to use the following:

```
write-output "First line" | out-file -encoding ascii OutputFileName
write-output "Next line" | out-file -encoding ascii -append OutputFileName
....
```

Changing the output encoding using:

```
$OutputEncoding = New-Object -typename System.Text.ASCIIEncoding
```

did not work

Comment: Indeed, `$OutputEncoding` does _not_ apply here, because it is unrelated to `>` / `>>` / `Out-File` (or _any_ cmdlet, for that matter). Its sole purpose is to define the encoding to use when sending data from PowerShell _to an external program_. However, that observation would have gained more exposure as a comment on the highly up-voted, but partially incorrect, accepted answer (I've since posted a comment - let's hope the answer gets fixed). You then wouldn't have needed to post an answer of your own (the rest of which duplicates Shay Levy's older answer).

Answer (score 3):

You can set the default encoding of out-file to be ascii:

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues=@{'out-file:encoding'='ascii'}
```

Then something like this will result in an ascii file:

```
echo hi > out
```

In powershell 6 and 7, the default encoding of out-file was changed to utf8 no bom.

Comment: Indeed, but note that in Windows PowerShell this [only works in the latest - and final - version, v5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40098904/45375). Also worth mentioning that (BOM-less) UTF-8 is PowerShell Core's (v6+) default encoding across _all_ cmdlets.

Answer (score 2):

Just a little example using streams, although I realize this wasn't the original question.

```
C:\temp\ConfirmWrapper.ps1 -Force -Verbose 4>&1 6>&1 | Out-File -Encoding default -FilePath C:\temp\confirmLog.txt -Append
```

Will output the information(6) and verbose(4) streams to the output(1) stream and redirect all that to the out-file with ANSI(default) encoding.