# How to unstash only certain files?

Tags: git, git-stash

I stashed my changes. Now I want to unstash only some files from the stash. How can I do this?

Comment: I think you have to apply the whole stash, but then you can selectively re-stash.

Comment: Just in your future development, try to avoid stashing files commit them instead, because git stash is not recommended

Comment: @AbdouTahiri What is wrong with the stash?

Comment: @alex With "git stash", you can have multiple different stashed things too, but they don't queue up on each other - they are just random independent patches that you've stashed away because they were inconvenient at some point.

Comment: @AbdouTahiri Uhhhh.. git stash is a legit feature, and extremely useful. I use it daily. Say, a coworker needs me to review something but I'm in the middle of a complex change set. I'm not going to commit a pile of broken code just so I can switch branches. I'm going to stash, switch branches, review, switch back, unstash. Do you care to elaborate on *who* or *why* git stash is supposedly "not recommended"? Just because *your* git stash history is muddied up and hard to read doesn't mean everyone elses is. A messy git stash set is just bad workflow, not a flaw of Git.

Comment: @alex Nothing. Nothing is wrong with git stash. Keep using it.

Comment: I thought it might be possible to patch an already changed file using `git show stash@{0} -- <filename> | git apply --check` but it keeps saying `fatal: unrecognized input`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would I extract a single file (or changes to a file) from a git stash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105253/how-would-i-extract-a-single-file-or-changes-to-a-file-from-a-git-stash)

Comment: this is trivial in [emacs magit mode](https://magit.vc/), sorry command line people. It is literally 3 key presses

Comment: dudewad, i would be much better to never have a "pile of broken code," and what's more, never branch.

Answer (score 685, accepted):

As [mentioned below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22555169/6309), and detailed in "[How would I extract a single file (or changes to a file) from a git stash?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1105666/6309)", you can apply use [`git checkout`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) or [`git show`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-show) to restore a specific file.

```
git checkout stash@{0} -- <filename>
```

With Git 2.23+ (August 2019), use [`git restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore), which replaces the [confusing `git checkout` command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309):

```
git restore --source=stash@{0} -- <filename>
```

That does **overwrite** `filename`: make sure you didn't have local modifications, or you might want to merge the [stashed file instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50370632/6309).

(As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15264553/how-to-unstash-only-certain-files/15264717#comment79042145_15264717) by [Jaime M.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/403616/jaime-m), for certain shell like tcsh where you need to escape the special characters, the syntax would be:  `git checkout 'stash@{0}' -- <filename>`)

> or to save it under another filename:

```
git show stash@{0}:<full filename>  >  <newfile>
```

> (note that here `<full filename>` is full pathname of a file relative to top directory of a project (think: relative to `stash@{0}`)).

[yucer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/469294/yucer) suggests [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15264553/how-to-unstash-only-certain-files/15264717?noredirect=1#comment63627960_15264717):

> If you want to select manually which changes you want to apply from that file:

```
git difftool stash@{0}..HEAD -- <filename>
# or
git checkout -p stash@{0} -- <filename>
```

[Vivek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/970301/vivek) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15264553/how-to-unstash-only-certain-files/15264717?noredirect=1#comment67306500_15264717):

> Looks like "`git checkout stash@{0} -- <filename>`" restores the version of the file as of the time when the stash was performed -- it does *NOT* apply (just) the stashed changes for that file.
> To do the latter:

```
git diff stash@{0}^1 stash@{0} -- <filename> | git apply
```

(as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15264553/how-to-unstash-only-certain-files/15264717?noredirect=1#comment70115895_15264717) by [peterflynn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1172352/peterflynn), you might need `| git apply -p1` in some cases, removing one (`p1`) leading slash from traditional diff paths)

---

As commented: "unstash" (`git stash pop`), then:

- add what you want to keep to the index (`git add`)
- stash the rest: `git stash --keep-index`

The last point is what allows you to keep some file while stashing others.
It is illustrated in "[How to stash only one file out of multiple files that have changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040833/how-to-stash-only-one-file-out-of-multiple-files-that-have-changed)".

Comment: This doesn't work if you can't `git stash pop` due to file conflicts. Balamurugan A's answer did the trick for me in that case.

Comment: Of if you want to select manually which changes you want to apply from that file you can use git difftool stash@{0}..HEAD -- <filename>

Comment: @yucer Nice. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Looks like "git checkout stash@{0} -- <filename>" restores the version of the file as of the time when the stash was performed -- it does NOT apply (just) the stashed changes for that file. To do the latter: "git diff stash@{0}^1 stash@{0} -- <filename> | git apply"

Comment: I ran into a case where the `| git apply` trick (to merge the stashed copy with the local copy) failed with the error "patch does not apply."  But using `| patch -p1` instead, the merge worked perfectly!

Comment: @peterflynn Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Note that you have to _escape_ the special characters in some shells like tcsh, so the command will be `git checkout 'stash@{0}' -- <file-name>`

Comment: @JaimeM. Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Assuming that `unstash` means `pop`, as it seems to me that it probably would in most cases, this only partially answers the question.  How do you then remove the selectively applied pieces from the stash in order to avoid later conflicts and/or confusion when popping the remaining changes?

Comment: @DylanYoung Not sure: do you have a specific case in mind? Otherwise, pop + add + stash --keep-index (mentioned at the end of this answer) seems pretty straightforward.

Comment: If you have existing changes that you're merging with select bits from the stash, then updating to make it all fit together, it can get messy.  Of course, a temporary commit and then squashing it together with the stashed changes would work, but it requires knowing what you're doing *very* well.  Whereas a command like `stash pop --interactive`, while technically complex to implement, is much less finicky for the user.

Comment: You're of course correct though, that the guts of such a command would almost certainly involve something like what you've outlined, similarly to the way `stash -u` just creates some support commits to work.  Just curious if there is a supported solution (or if it's on the timeline) and pointing out that, the given solutions are not super clean and or require a lot of overhead on the part of the user to make sure relevant changes stay where they're supposed to and don't get all mixed up..

Comment: @DylanYoung OK. I am not aware of such a solution right now.

Comment: Why do I get `$ git checkout stash@{0} --filename ./myFile.java
error: unknown option `filename'
`

Comment: @JanacMeena because there should be a space between the '`--`' and the filename (as there is in the answer above). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1192194/6309 for more on the '`--`' notation.

Comment: @VonC thanks! Also, how do I pop a specific file from my stash, (rather than just apply it) if this file doesn't currently exist in my working directory - it only exists in the stash?

Comment: @JanacMeena  The `git show stash@{0}:<full filename>  >  <newfile>` command should be able to create that file  in the working tree, even if it existed *only* in the stash.

Comment: @VonCgit checkout stash@{0} -- <filename> will replace with stash changes.

Comment: @AkhilSurapuram Exactly. That is the idea. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50370632/6309 would merge instead of overriding. I will edit the answer to make the distinction clearer.

Comment: @AkhilSurapuram I have edited the answer to emphasize the consequence of that `git checkout stash@{0} -- <filename>` command.

Comment: In my Windows command prompt (git 2.36.0), `git restore --source='stash@{0}' -- <my_file>` returned an error: "fatal: could not resolve 'stash@{0}'". It required "stash@{0}" without single quotes.

Comment: @Arkane Thank you for the feedback. I have edited the answer accordingly and remove the single quotes.

Comment: `>If you want to select manually which changes you want to apply from that file:` Would it be better to use `git checkout -p` instead of `git difftool`?

Comment: @EugenKonkov Yes, `git checkout -p stash@{0} -- <filename>` would work too. It is not "better", just different (GUI vs. CLI)

Answer (score 135):

```
git checkout stash@{N} <File(s)/Folder(s) path>
```

Eg.
To restore only ./test.c file and ./include folder from last stashed,

```
git checkout stash@{0} ./test.c ./include
```

Comment: This is the correct answer!  Single line command to apply only stashed changes from specific files, works like a charm!

Comment: To apply (just) the stashed changes for the file: "git diff stash@{N}^1 stash@{N} -- <filename> | git apply"

Comment: This works for me too. Just selectively checkout the files needed to use from stash and you are done. I was stuck in this a I had used `-a` flag while creating the stash.

Comment: @4levels I think  "apply stashed changes" is not what happens, right?  I think  "overwrite whatever you have with the copy from stash" is what happens.

Answer (score 43):

First list all the stashes

```
git stash list
```

↓

```
stash@{0}: WIP on Produktkonfigurator: 132c06a5 Cursor bei glyphicon plus und close zu zeigende Hand ändern
stash@{1}: WIP on Produktkonfigurator: 132c06a5 Cursor bei glyphicon plus und close zu zeigende Hand ändern
stash@{2}: WIP on master: 7e450c81 Merge branch 'Offlineseite'
```

Then show which files are in the stash (lets pick stash 1):

```
git stash show 1 --name-only

//Hint: you can also write
//git stash show stash@{1} --name-only
```

↓

```
 ajax/product.php
 ajax/productPrice.php
 errors/Company/js/offlineMain.phtml
 errors/Company/mage.php
 errors/Company/page.phtml
 js/konfigurator/konfigurator.js
```

Then apply the file you like to:

```
git checkout stash@{1} -- <filename>
```

or whole folder:

```
git checkout stash@{1} /errors
```

---

It also works without `--` but it is recommended to use them. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1192194/4684797) post.

> It is also conventional to recognize a double hyphen as a signal to
>   stop option interpretation and treat all following arguments
>   literally.

Comment: I tried many ways and this way was the one I needed. I was faced with a problem that `git stash pop` thrown an error for untracked files. thank you.

Answer (score 41):

I think VonC's answer is probably what you want, but here's a way to do a selective "git apply":

```
git show stash@{0}:MyFile.txt > MyFile.txt
```

Comment: This might be what you want in some cases, but beware that this command will **overwrite** rather than merge with any working directory changes.

Comment: This works for me, since I just wanted to copy a file that exists only in the stash and didn't care to `checkout` anything.

Comment: For Windows PowerShell: `git show stash@\`{0\`}:Path/To/MyFile.txt |sc Path/To/MyFile.txt` - the backticks are necessary for PS to not interpret the braces specially, and the `sc` is necessary [because PS's `>` operator defaults to UTF-16 (actually UCS-2)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1709427/70345) which is probably not what you want. [@Balamurugan A's answer doesn't suffer from these issues.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22555169/70345)

Answer (score 18):

One more way:

```
git diff stash@{N}^! -- path/to/file1 path/to/file2  | git apply -R
```

Comment: This is the only correct answer IMO. Using `checkout` or `show` will blindly overwrite your file instead of just applying changes. "One more way" is an understatement.

Comment: I'm not getting the `path/to/file2` as the you want to diff against the same file in your workspace. Leaving out the second path works fine for me. - And I get an error message using the `-R` option ("apply the patch in reverse", trying to patch the stashed version?!). So my working version looks like
`git diff stash@{N}^! -- path/to/file | git apply -` .

Comment: "patch failed"?  Try a 3-way merge. `...| git apply -3 -`

Comment: `diff stash@{N}^!` already  produces a forward diff, so omit  `-R`

Comment: The ^! did not work in my case, so I ended up doing `git diff stash@{N} -- path/to/file | git apply -R`

Answer (score 15):

For Windows users: curly braces have special meaning in PowerShell. You can either surround with single quotes or escape with backtick. For example:

`git checkout 'stash@{0}' YourFile`

Without it, you may receive an error:

`Unknown switch 'e'`

Answer (score 13):

If you `git stash pop` (with no conflicts) it will remove the stash after it is applied.  But if you `git stash apply` it will apply the patch without removing it from the stash list.  Then you can revert the unwanted changes with `git checkout -- files...`

Comment: To clarify the conflicts part of this post, if you `git stash pop` and there ARE conflicts, you will have to fix them manually and the stash will NOT be removed.

Answer (score 4):

For examle

```
git stash show --name-only
```

result

```
ofbiz_src/.project
ofbiz_src/applications/baseaccounting/entitydef/entitymodel_view.xml
ofbiz_src/applications/baselogistics/webapp/baselogistics/delivery/purchaseDeliveryDetail.ftl
ofbiz_src/applications/baselogistics/webapp/baselogistics/transfer/listTransfers.ftl
ofbiz_src/applications/component-load.xml
ofbiz_src/applications/search/config/elasticSearch.properties
ofbiz_src/framework/entity/lib/jdbc/mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar
ofbiz_src/framework/entity/lib/jdbc/postgresql-9.3-1101.jdbc4.jar
```

Then pop stash in specific file

```
git checkout stash@{0} -- ofbiz_src/applications/baselogistics/webapp/baselogistics/delivery/purchaseDeliveryDetail.ftl
```

other related commands

```
git stash list --stat
get stash show
```

Answer (score 3):

For windows user to avoid `Unknown switch 'e'` the `stash@{0}` needs to surround inside quote as shown below

`git restore --source='stash@{0}' -- <filename>`

Answer (score 0):

```
git stash apply // apply all files
git reset . // reset all
git add <wanted_file> // add only wanted file(s)
git checkout . // negate changes of the other files
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?