# stashed some code but don't know which stash it is in - how to figure out?

Tags: git, git-stash

I wrote considerable code for a feature and stashed the changes in git.

After that I pushed several changes into the repository and did a git stash and apply multiple times (read over 100 times).

After almost 2 months I now want to retrieve the changes from git stash –
but I cant find them no matter what.

Tried several `git stash apply`, `git stash list`, `git stash list -p`. Nothing works. I cant find those old stashed changes.

Wish I had taken a backup instead of trusting git to stash them...sigh...

Can anyone help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git: how to unstash only certain files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15264553/git-how-to-unstash-only-certain-files)

Comment: A stash is held only in the repository which stored them originally - it is not copied with clone, push or pull.  Are you running in the same repository?  Did you ever check these changes in to HEAD?

Comment: Did the output from `git stash list` show *anything*

Comment: Git stash is not a reliable long term store for changes.  It's generally better to commit and them move them aside into a separate branch.

Comment: @Alex Brown - yes it is the same repository, not cloned after that fateful git stash.  "git stash list" shows a whole big list.

Comment: @Luceos - That other question seems to be talking about the {0} stash. But my problem is I dont know where my changes are stashed and which stash number they are on

Comment: well, look through the stashes like `git show 'stash@{0}'`, `git show 'stash@{1}'` etc to find your code.  the single quotes are important, because `{` is a bash metacharacter.

Comment: Ah, can you reword your question - such as 'I stashed some code but don't know which stash it is in'

Comment: Thank you @Alex Brown - the tip about 'stash@{0}' helped

Comment: FYI: You can use git stash show 0, git stash show 1, etc... I haven't seen it documented anywhere, but it works at least in git version 2.19.0

Answer (score 19):

Try this:

```
git stash list -p | grep 'diff --git' | grep <your file name>
```

That will find your files in the list. It might take a while.

One thing: `git stash apply` does not discard a stash. After a successful apply, you should `git stash drop` so it dos not clutter your list. Personally, I apply the stash using `git stash pop`.

Comment: Nice - I like `git stash list -p`, I hadn't seen that before.

Comment: Thank you for the help @Alex Siri. The stash pop tip helped

Comment: Isn't `git stash pop` evil?

Comment: The problem with this is that it simply shows the diff line 1 or more times, but you don't know what stash are they in.

Answer (score 17):

To search inside the changes in your stashes, use `git stash list` with the pickaxe option `-G` (from `git log`):

```
git stash list -G regex_matching_some_added_or_removed_string
```

Comment: Thanks to @VonC for the tip about `git log` options.

Answer (score 7):

This is the command I use.  It helps me identify which stash is being referred to.

```
git stash list | while IFS=: read STASH ETC; do echo "$STASH: $ETC"; git diff --stat $STASH~..$STASH --; done | grep -e 'stash\|<partial_name_of_file_being_searched_for>'
```

I also use it in conjunction with an alias in my `.bashrc` file like so:

```
function gitsearch()
{
   searchCrit='stash\|'$1
   git stash list | while IFS=: read STASH ETC; do echo "$STASH: $ETC"; git diff --stat $STASH~..$STASH --; done | grep -e $searchCrit
}
alias githunt=gitsearch
```

The end result being that I can search my git stashes thus:

`githunt LoanApplicationFee`

and get the following results where I can quickly see that stash 45 has what I'm looking for:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Note: in case of **stashed merged commit**, a `git stash list -p` would return nothing.
That will change with Git 2.2 (Q4 2014) and [commit 288c67c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/288c67caf64af111aeb7c45cb8b6ba586a61c724) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff):

### `stash`: default listing to working-tree diff

> When you list stashes, you can provide arbitrary `git log` options to change the display. However, **adding just "`-p`" does nothing, because each stash is actually a merge commit**.
>
> This implementation detail is easy to forget, leading to confused users who think "`-p`" is not working. We can make this easier by defaulting to "`--first-parent -m`", which will
>   show the diff against the working tree.
>   This omits the index portion of the stash entirely, but it's simple and it matches what "`git stash show`" provides.
>
> People who are more clueful about stash's true form can use "`--cc`" to override the "`-m`", and the "`--first-parent`" will then do nothing.
>   For diffs, it only affects non-combined diffs, so "`--cc`" overrides it.
>   And for the traversal, we are walking the linear reflog anyway, so we do not even care
>   about the parents.

Answer (score 5):

If you have only a few stashes listed in `git stash list` then you can examine them one by one to see if they are the correct one:

```
git show 'stash@{0}'
git show 'stash@{1}'
```

etc.

If you have some code in **many** stashes, and can remember a string or keyword you typed in a file which (almost) uniquely identifies that code (I use `DUNKIRK` here), search for it using the following `bash` command.

```
for i in `git reflog --pretty=format:%H stash`; do git grep DUNKIRK $i; done
```

note that git grep searches the whole checkout - not just the changes.

Compare the answer from @siri, which searches for filenames which are changed in the stashes - which is another useful strategy.

Alternatively, to search only the diffs

```
 git reflog -p stash | less
```

and then search for your strings OR files, or just browse it.  This might be large.

Comment: `git reflog -p stash` is probably the same logic as `git stash list -p` from @siri's answer.

Answer (score 1):

A combination of git commands from the above answers helped me with what I need. Posting my answer here as it might help others and because I cant accept any one single answer/comment

```
git stash list -p - showed me the list of stashes

git stash pop 'stash@{12}' - popped out the 12th stash which contains my code.
```