# Is there a graphical way to git stash/unstash individual files?

Tags: git, git-stash

I am looking for a GUI for stashing and stash popping files in git, with the ability to do so for individual modified files.  I know there is a command line way to do so, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15264553/git-how-to-unstash-only-certain-files), but I am looking for a graphical way.  I don't care so much about stashing individual files, but more about popping/applying. I am running on Windows 7.

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is off-topic. Stack Overflow is not about software recommendations.

Comment: @Jubobs, okay, I thought of it as a "I need a way to solve my specific problem", not "which git gui client is the best".

Comment: Your OS? On Windows, GitExtensions could do that...

Comment: @Philippe, Windows (I just added to question).  Now that you mention it, I can select the stash in my tree and probably copy files over that way.  Other than that, I'm not sure how to do individual files.

Comment: You have a problem but you are looking for the solution in the wrong direction. [`git stash`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) was designed for a different thing (it is explained in the first paragraph of its documentation). You can do what you want (and in a more flexible way than stashing) if you create a new branch and commit the changes on it (in any amount of combination you want) until you reach the status you desire. Then just checkout the previous branch and you're done.

Comment: @axiac, I think you are right. I'm using git coming from Perforce, so I'm trying to make stash fit in the 'shelve' mold, but I think branching is the better way to do it.  Tied to this is that git extensions sort of makes a branch out of my stashes, so I may be able to stash but treat it like a branch when grabbing individual files.

Comment: @axiac, if you post that as your answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation of [`git stash`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) says:

> Use `git stash` when you want to record the current state of the working directory and the index, but want to go back to a clean working directory. The command saves your local modifications away and reverts the working directory to match the `HEAD` commit.

It provides very little support<sup>1</sup> to handle individual files because its purpose is to safely store your current changes and quickly bring your working tree to a clean state (i.e. as it was immediately after your last commit on the current branch).

You can do what you want (and in a more flexible way than stashing) if you create a new branch and commit the changes on it (in any amount or combination you want) until you reach the status you desire. Then just checkout the previous branch and you're done.

This approach allows you to merge the changes into the current branch later, to cherry-pick only some commits or even some files from them.

---

<sup>1</sup> `git stash save` provides the option `--patch` that allows the user to interactively selects hunks from the diff between `HEAD` and the working tree to be stashed. It allows fine control over what is added to the stash.

#### Extra discussion

You say:

> I'm using `git` coming from `Perforce`, so I'm trying to make stash fit in the 'shelve' mold, but I think branching is the better way to do it. Tied to this is that [`gitextensions`](https://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/) sort of makes a branch out of my stashes, so I may be able to stash but treat it like a branch when grabbing individual files.

Internally, each stash is [stored as a commit](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#_discussion) linked to the commit that was the `HEAD` at the moment when the stash was created, but not linked to the previous stash (if any). The list of stashes is stored as meta-data; the stashes are **not linked** in a (hidden) branch.

More, `git stash create` allows the creation of a stash without adding it into the list of stashes. It is provided for scripting and *"probably not the command you want to use"* (I quoted from the documentation).

Comment: thanks.  To clarify, I don't think the stash really is like a branch, but git extensions makes it appear so - which can be good or bad.  git extensions provides a layer of abstractions, and sometimes it's not exactly clear what I'm doing.

Comment: Indeed, [gitextensions](https://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/) makes the list of stashes look like a branch; while this can help the beginners accommodate with `git` easier, it misleads them later. [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com) presents the stashes as independent objects, the same way it shows the branches, the tags and the remotes. Give it a try (it's free), maybe you'll like it. It is also a Mercurial client.

Comment: "The list of stashes is stored as meta-data" - as far as I can see in the refs/logs/stash basically. What is `git save` you refer to ?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D it should have been `git stash save`, I forgot the `stash` when I wrote the answer. I fixed it now. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 17):

I saw a recommendation [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/git-version-control/roaCwkQs7_c) to add the Stash commands as a menu to "Git GUI" in your `<USER HOME directory>\.gitconfig`.

```
[guitool "Stash/show"]
  cmd = git stash show -p
[guitool "Stash/list"]
  cmd = git stash list
[guitool "Stash/pop"]
  cmd = git stash pop
[guitool "Stash/drop"]
  cmd = git stash drop
  confirm = yes
```

I also added one more command to do the stashing (to use, you must first stage--but not commit--the files you wish stashed in order for Git to perform the required "add"):

```
[guitool "Stash"]
  cmd = git stash
```

(Note that I chose to have "stash" not appear as a submenu, but you could do so.)

You can also add commands through Git GUI itself via Tools->Add.

Stashing can be helpful if you just want to put the files out of mind quickly without bothering to think of a branch name.

Answer (score 5):

Did you try Sourcetree:
http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/

It might solve your problem.

Comment: SourceTree is a good `Git` GUI client but it cannot stash individual files. Maybe this is because the `stash` command was not designed to work this way?