# 'git am < MyFix.patch' command error in Powershell

Tags: git, powershell, stdin

How do we get this command to run on Powershell with out error : The '<' operator is reserved for future use.

```
C:\Users\Me\my-git-repo > git am < MyFix.patch
    The '<' operator is reserved for future use.
    At line:1 char:9
    + git am < <<<<  MyFix.patch
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (<:OperatorToken) [],..      
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RedirectionNotSupported
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use either:

```
Get-Content MyFix.patch | git am
```

or:

```
cmd /c 'git am < MyFix.patch'
```

Both should work equally well. Windows Powershell simply doesn't support IO redirection with `<` for now, so you either need to pipe the text to stdin using `|` (`Get-Content`<sup>[1]</sup> sends the contents of MyFix.patch to stdout and `|` feeds it along to `git am`'s stdin); alternatively, run the command through CMD.exe.

---

<sup>[1] Alternatively, use the built-in alias `type`.</sup>

Comment: @ashishp, for the future, please notice that PowerShell is roally screwed up with regard to character encoding when using stream redirection: it uses UTF-16 for this unless told otherwise. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1707397/720999) for one example. So if you need to work with Git *and* use stream redirection, consider using plain old `cmd.exe` or use one of [better alternative console implementations](http://superuser.com/q/268042/130459) or use Git bash (which is shipped with GfW).

Comment: @kostix: UTF-16 as the default in Windows PowerShell only applies to `>` / `>>`, i.e., _output redirection_, which does _not_ come into play in _pipelines_.
There, it is the value of preference variable `$OutputEncoding` that determines how strings sent to _external programs_ are encoded. Unfortunately, however,
the default is to use _ASCII_ encoding, which means that non-ASCII characters are lost (transliterated to literal `?` chars.) In short: `$OutputEncoding` is what
you need to adjust if your output contains non-ASCII chars.

Comment: @kostix: P.S.:  Note that the cross-platform [PowerShell _Core_](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell) edition (available since early 2018) sensibly defaults to _BOM-less UTF-8_ in these scenarios.