# How can I avoid that echo in Windows PowerShell creates binary files?

Tags: powershell, echo

I am a long-time Linux user and am used to a command like:

```
echo 'hello' > a.txt
```

creating a plaintext file simply containing 'hello'.

Now, if I use the same command in Windows PowerShell, the resulting file is claimed to be binary (by git). If I inspect the file in a text editor, the file contains the text but some weird excessive characters that look like a character encoding issue.

How am I supposed to use `echo` instead to make it behave in a completely "ordinary" plaintext way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using redirection within the script produces a unicode output. How to emit single-byte ASCII text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707397/using-redirection-within-the-script-produces-a-unicode-output-how-to-emit-singl)

Comment: Ah OK, that seems related. It could sound like the `echo` output gets UTF-16 encoded and then git may have a problem, cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777949/can-i-make-git-recognize-a-utf-16-file-as-text

Comment: FWIW [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/powershell/powershell) aka PowerShell 6 (which is specifically designed to work well on Linux and thus play nice with things like Git as well) uses a more sensible default of UTF-8 without a BOM.

Comment: See also the accepted answer to this question [changing-powershells-default-output-encoding-to-utf-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40098771/changing-powershells-default-output-encoding-to-utf-8)

Comment: @ThomasArildsen it's not the use of `echo` that causes it - it's the default behavior of `>` that causes UTF-16LE encoding